# Blessed - listen for any key

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

I am using node with the blessed tty library from NPM.  in it I can use a method "**key**" like the below:

```
blessed.key(['q', 'z'], function(ch, key) {
    //do something  
});
```

how do I get this to listen to any key-press without having to specify the key I want to listen for - and WITHOUT using the onkey event blessed provides.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
var blessed = require('blessed');

var screen = blessed.screen({
  smartCSR: true
});

screen.on('keypress', function(key) {
  console.log(key);
});
```

I'm not sure this is "the onkey event blessed provides" that you want to avoid. Also I'm not sure why you want to avoid that in the first place.

Comment: If you're downvoting this answer, please at least explain why it's not good enough.

Comment: It should be: `screen.on('keypress', function(_, key) {
  console.log(key);
});`